# Redirect tr output to kafka-console-producer in docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker, apache-kafka, tr

I redirect file to kafka-console-producer inside a docker container with:

```
docker exec -i $(docker ps -a | grep "cluster-1-kafka" | grep Up | awk '{print $1}') bash -c " \
printf '%s\n%s\n' 'security.protocol=PLAINTEXT' 'sasl.mechanism=PLAIN' > prop && \
kafka-console-producer --producer.config=prop  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic events" < message.json
```

Since `kafka-console-producer` treats every line in the file as a separate message, I need to remove newlines from the file with `tr -d '\n' < message.json`

How to redirect `tr` output to `docker exec` input?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you should be using `tr` as any bad invocation of that will break your JSON. Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead

For example, `< <(jq -c . < message.json)`

Comment: it returns `-bash:{"message text"}: No such file or directory`

Comment: `< <(cat message.json | jq -c .)` works out. Thank you .

Comment: Ah, yeah, I wasn't sure the correct symbol there

Answer (score 0):

Get it done with  `< <(tr -d '\n' < message.json)`